# How to do a fast DELETE of lots of data from a large table (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

I want to delete about 90% of rows from a million+ row table. Anything I can do to make this faster? e.g. if I turn on Simple Recovery Mode will this help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy the rows your don't want to delete into a temporary table using [select into](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp), and then [truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621%28SQL.80%29.aspx) the table rather than delete. The copy the rows back into the old table. Remember to [drop contraints](http://ss64.com/ora/table_a_cons.html) first.

If you have identity columns, after renter the data, use something like this to reseed the table.

```
declare @seed int
select @seed = max(identity_col)+1 from tableName
DBCC CHECKIDENT (orders, table_name, @seed)
```

Comment: nice! I have identity columns so would have to deal with that, but that's ok.

Comment: +1 - This is minimally logged in at least 2005+ (not sure about prior versions) so it should be super quick.  Bear in mind the time needed to rebuild indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want to delete 90% of rows, it might be fastest to SELECT INTO those 10% rows you want to keep into a new table.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not copy the rest to another table, then truncate and copy back...

...dropping indices is about the only thing you can do programming wise. In this case dropping indices and recreating them may help.

...or get a faster disc subsystem, mostly for the data.

Recovery mode will not help - recovery mode says the log is deletable immediately after the (can bbe implicit) commit, but there is nothing in it that avoids the log entries from being writte.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `IsDeleted (BIT)` flag, set that to 1 for those 90%, and create a view over your table which only shows the rows with `IsDeleted=0`.

Deleting is always a) a resource-intensive operation, and b) destroys any possibility of accountability - I would try to avoid it if ever possible, for both reasons (performance and data destruction). Use the "soft delete" approach instead.